# How to append text area and select html element values to a javascript object of type FormData?

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using an ajax upload plugin and I want to append a textarea and select element values to my object of type FormData, ie `data`. How do I this? please help me.

```
var $this = $(this);
if ( typeof upfiles[count] === 'undefined') return false;
$( document ).ready( function() {

var count = 0;
var percentComplete = 0;
var upfiles = 0;

$(".progressbar").hide();
$( '#uploadcontainer' ).on( 'upload', '#fileToUpload' , function( ) {

var $this = $(this);
if ( typeof upfiles[count] === 'undefined') return false;
var data = new FormData();
var file = upfiles[count];
data.append( 'file', file );

currfile = file.name;
fileext = currfile.substr( -3 );

if( fileext == "php" || fileext == ".js" ) {
count++;
$( '#uplcomp' ).append( 'Oopz,Error'+'<br />' + file.name + ' not an image' + '<br />' );// appending progress bar
$this.trigger('upload');
}
else 
{
    $.ajax({
url: 'upload.php',
type:'POST',
data: data ,
```

Comment: What is the name of your Ajax plugin?

Comment: Ajax file upload with jQuery and PHP
http://techlister.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-with-jquery-and-php/802/

Comment: Hey guy, can you edit the post and put all your jscript in there please?

Comment: Sure,thank you for trying to helping me..I've edited it to my own.

Comment: did 'data.append('caption', caption.value);' not work?

Comment: I'm still not seeing everything, unless 'data' is the variable you're referring to when you say 'newFormData' in your question

Comment: I think it'll will work.Previosly i used data.append(caption,caption);
thank you for the help

Comment: var data = new FormData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will edit this answer if it doesn't satisfy your problem, but have you tried doing this?:

```
data.append('caption', $("#caption").val());
data.append('Privacy', $("#Privacy").val());
```

get back to me if you have any more problems

Comment: data.append('Privacy', $("#Privacy").val()); 
Works but 
data.append('caption', $("#caption").text()); doesn't.I changed $("#caption").text() to $("#caption").val() .Now it works fine.Thank you so much...

Comment: yup, I had it as .text() initially
I've had problems referencing the text of such elements with a .val() function.

no problem man, anytime.

could you mark my answer as accepted please :D

Comment: :D thanks agen..How can i mark that?I'm new to satckoverflow.

Comment: there should be a tick under the voting part to the top left of my answer, if you click the tick it becomes green

Comment: thanks man, welcome to stackoverflow, you're prolly a young programmer like me, you'll learn a lot and get a lotta help here everytime you try new stuff.
cya